# Auth failing when using Devart ODBC connector to mLab

Tags: mongodb, odbc, powerbi

I'm trying to connect PowerBI to a mLab-hosted Mongodb instance.

I first tried installing the [MongoDB BI-connector](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#bi-connector), but after installing it didn't show up on the drivers list in Windows ODBC manager (neither 64 or 32 bit)

I then tried installing Devart's trial version Mongo ODBC driver. This showed up in Windows ODBC manager, but when I tried setting up and testing a connection I get Authentication Failed.
I tried setting authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1 in the Advanced Connection Options but it didn't help.
I also tried adding a new user on mlab.

Any suggestions on figuring out where the problem is would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, if you're still having issues, can you please email support@mlab.com? We'll be better able to help troubleshoot authentication issues over private email.

Comment: Great, thanks @AdamHarrison, will do.